# JavaScript: Conditioned button creation and removal

Tags: javascript, button

I have to solve a problem which sounds like this:

I have a HTML file with:
 1 input
 1 select with no value
 1 button - 'Start'

After pressing the Start button, new buttons will be created from 3 to 3 seconds, with the names and ids 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', until reaching the value entered in the input.

Clicking on a button so created, it will disappear, and its id will appear as an option in select.

This is what I have done until now, but I don't know how to continue..

```
window.onload
{
    document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].onclick = function ()
    {
        if(document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value > 0)
          {
              var i=1;
              var n = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;

              var addButtons = setInterval(function() 
              { 

                if(i==n) clearInterval(addButtons);

                var button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
                button.setAttribute("id", "b"+i);

                document.body.appendChild(button);

                i=i+1;

              }, 3000);
          }
    };

}
```

Comment: What you mean `created from 3 to 3 seconds` ?

Answer (score 0):

**1-** Instead of using `document.getElementsByTagName` use `document.querySelectorAll` because of perfomance issues.

**2-** Define this event listener for each new button

```
button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.target.style.display = 'none';
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  option.innerHTML = e.target.name;
  document.querySelectorAll("select")[0].append(option)
});
```

Full code

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].onclick = function() {
  if (document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value > 0) {
    var i = 1;
    var n = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;

    var addButtons = setInterval(function() {

      if (i == n) clearInterval(addButtons);

      var button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
      button.setAttribute("id", "b" + i);
      button.setAttribute("name", "b" + i);
      button.innerHTML = "B" + i;

      button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.target.style.display = 'none';
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.innerHTML = e.target.name;
        document.querySelectorAll("select")[0].append(option)
      });

      document.body.appendChild(button);

      i = i + 1;

    }, 3000);
  }
};
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>

<input type="number" />

<select></select>
```